# imagemagick syntaxerror in pdfopen

Tags: imagemagick, ghostscript, file-conversion

I am trying to do PDF to Image conversion. The command I used to do conversion is

```
convert -density 150 -define registry:temporary-path=/tmp "original_1492599526_Management__CRC.pdf" -quality 50 "imgmagick1492599530_%09d.jpg"
```

After running above conversion command on red hat linux(rhel 6) machine getting bellow error.

I gone through these links but no help.

```
http://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=17790
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1027534
http://forums.justlinux.com/showthread.php?130769-Ghostscript-fails-to-read-PDF-strange-error
```

[image]

Any help appriciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an archaic version of Ghostscript, if I read that error correctly.

Version 8.70 is now 7 years old. I would suggest that you upgrade to the current version and try again.

If the problem persists then you are going to need to post an example file somewhere to look at. A screenshot of an error doesn't tell me much.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, let me try upgrade and comeback.

Comment: I tried in other local machine with Ghostscript 8.70, its working fine. Only its not working production servers

Comment: So what ? Nobody is going to be able to help you with 7 year old code. Try the current version, if it works, then problem solved. If it doesn't work, then you need to post an example file where people can look at it.